# Displaying different values from database in different columns from same table

Tags: php, sql, database

Following is my code in which i am trying to display the values from the same table but in different columns  of my HTML table with different ids like lets suppose my table has three columns then in each column the distinct value get displayed

**All i want that my respective id changes on each column of the data being displayed from same table**

Something like :  Values of ID1  |  Values of ID2   |   Values of ID3

But currently my do while is working something like this:
  Values of ID1  |   Values of ID1   |   Values of ID1

Kindly let me know how can i fix my following code:

```
          <table width="714" height="318" border="0" align="right" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
          <?php $count=0; do { 
                  { ++$count;

          ?> <tr>
            <td width="231" height="288" valign="top" background="images/viv.png"><div align="center"><img src="get.php?id=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['ID']; ?>"  width="270" height="270" /><br />
                <br />
              <a href="get_deal.php?id=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['ID']; ?>"><img src="button.png" width="182" height="36" border="0" /></a><br />
              <br />
            </div></td>
            <td width="231" valign="top" background="images/viv.png"><div align="center"><img src="get.php?id=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['ID']; ?>"  width="270" height="270" /><br />
                    <br />
                    <a href="get_deal.php?id=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['ID']; ?>"><img src="button.png" width="182" height="36" border="0" /></a><br />
                    <br />
            </div></td>
            <td width="231" valign="top" background="images/viv.png"><div align="center"><img src="get.php?id=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['ID']; ?>"  width="270" height="270" /><br />
                    <br />
                    <a href="get_deal.php?id=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['ID']; ?>"><img src="button.png" width="182" height="36" border="0" /></a><br />
                    <br />
            </div></td>
          </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="23" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <?php }

              } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1));
if ($count == 0)
            echo '<span style="font-family:Tahoma;color:white;font-size:200%">No Deals Available</span>';   ?>
        </table></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

**SOLUTION:**
http://www.qualitycodes.com/tutorial.php?articleid=33&title=Displaying-Records-in-Multiple-Columns-Using-PHP

Comment: If you are displaying using tables, why not use <td></td> instead of <span>?

Comment: Are you sure this works as you expect?  It seems like for the first iteration of the loop, `$row_Recordset1` will not be set and you'll end up with links like `<a href="get_deal.php?id=">`.  This is because you're using a `do{...} while()` loop instead of a standard `while(){...}` loop.

Answer (score 3):

You keep echoing `$row_Recordset1['ID'];` which means you keep showing the ID column. You must change `ID` to the name of the column you want to display.

In this case they keep doing ID1 so if all three values are ID then you need to do aliases (call them different names) in your select so you can use `ID1`, `ID2` and `ID3`

For instance if your current sql query is:

```
select *
from tablex.....
```

Then you now have to extract the columns and name them:

```
select tablex.ID as ID1, secondTable.ID as ID2, thirdTable.ID as ID3
from tablex.....
```

and then you can refer to them as `ID1`, `ID2` and `ID3`.

Comment: hmmm yes you are right all three are ID so creating an alias will resolve the issue can you kindly give a hint of such query

Comment: That depends on your query.  But the general idea is to use the `AS` keyword.  For example: `SELECT table1.ID AS ID1, table2.ID AS ID2...`

Comment: the table is same.. So in that case if i do `table1.ID AS ID1, table1.ID As ID2 ` i dont think it'll gonna display the distinct values

Comment: Why do you have the same column name 3 times in your table? You should always have different column names. Because of that the database is probably just grabbing the first ID and not seeing the others.

Comment: how can i create such script that on second column id changes?

Comment: I would have to see you table schema and your current sql query. If you go to http://sqlfiddle.com/ you can select which sql you are using and set it up and then give me the new link so I can see

Comment: `$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM deals WHERE dealtype='Shoes' and status = 'Available'";` All i want is only that the id changes on each column thats all so always on second column there would be a distinct data....

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: I only see `ID` and `UID`. What are the three `ID` columns you are grabbing? It looks like you get `ID` once, `UID` once, and every other column once.

Comment: What i am trying to do on column 1 show records where id=1 then on column 2 show records where id=2  then on column 3 show records where id=3 and so on. In order to populate the data coming from database in columns

Comment: I kinda solved it myself what i do is create table with 3 columns and then copy the do while to each column that corresponds to same query..